# Where to find Laravel Goutte web scraper method usage documentation?

Tags: laravel-5, goutte

Where can i refer the **method usage** of Laravel 5 Goutte documentation?

For example:

->filter()

->each()

->text()

->attr()

Is that all?..

This is the documentation that i refer: https://www.fastfwd.com/website-scraper-using-laravel-goutte/

Thanks guys!

Comment: its not something official from laravel, therefore you won't find it

Comment: mmmmm I looked the link you passed and I was WRONG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the functions aren't from the 'Goutte' package. If you look carefully Goutte uses laravel collections, therefore all avaible methods of laravel collections can be used on the custom collections that packages creates.

The are a lot of aviable methods, you can find them explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods)(official laravel docs)

Answer (score 0):

laravel goutte actualy uses The [DomCrawler Component from](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)
, please check it for more information about available methods.